# How to Get Rid of the Shadow Above the Launcher Icon

Tags: 15.04, launcher, panel, shadow

I'm wanting to know how to get rid of the black/gray shadow above the launcher icon and below the panel that stretches across the top of the screen. It's on the the top 6-7 pixels (vertically across the launcher) of just the launcher. Below was the image :

[image]

The launcher and panel are both completely transparent because I changed them in Unity Tweak Tool, just for reference, and wanting to know how to get rid of this shadow.

Comment: Upload your picture on [Imgur](http://imgur.com) and then post link of picture

Answer (score 2):

I have just migrated to Ubuntu and tweaked the Unity Desktop environment to my heart's content. I wanted a nice flat material design theme for my desktop. Everything went well but the **launcher_bfb** button didn't change. It still had a shadow and a glow. After googling I found out that the icon is placed in the following directory: `/usr/share/unity/icons`.

The launcher_bfb icon is made up 13 different png and svg images (atleast in Ubuntu 16.04), namely,

1. launcher_bfb.png
2. launcher_icon_back_54.svg
3. launcher_icon_back_150.svg
4. launcher_icon_edge_54.svg
5. launcher_icon_edge_150.svg
6. launcher_icon_glow_62.svg
7. launcher_icon_glow_62.png
8. launcher_icon_glow_200.svg
9. launcher_icon_selected_back_54.svg
10. launcher_icon_selected_back_150.svg
11. launcher_icon_shadow_62.svg
12. launcher_icon_shadow_200.svg
13. launcher_icon_shine_54.svg

I just replaced these files (except the first one) with blank png/svg files of same dimensions and it worked for me.

Comment: Please mark this accepted if it has answered your query.