# Panel keeps showing what it was showing during Logon/Unlock on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: login, unity-dash, lock-screen, panel

I tried to remove the shadow from the launcher using [this answer as a guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/849723/740433). After doing so, I logged out to check whether or not I've succeeded (this was not the case, sadly).
However, I noticed a bigger problem: the menu-bar was stuck showing what it was showing during logon as a background. Upon further testing, opening and closing Dash refreshed the menu-bar again, but didn't keep it updated. [As you can see in this image, my computer's name is still shown in the top left and whatever the clock was showing during logon, making it mostly ineligible now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBCWj.png)

I don't think I changed any settings that could've done it, only edited the files mentioned in the guide with GIMP before the logout.

Update: I tried restarting my laptop. At first, it seemed that my problem was fixed. However, upon further inspection, it was only *partially* fixed. The background image was still stuck, but the menu-bar was at least not showing the old clock and updated the window name. Until I locked the laptop and unlocked. The clock and computer name from the lock screen were still being shown.

SOLVED: Switching Dash Blur in CompizConfig Settings Manager from "No Blur" to "Active Blur" and "Static Blur, then back to "No Blur" solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching Dash Blur in CompizConfig Settings Manager from "No Blur" to "Active Blur" and "Static Blur, then back to "No Blur" solved this issue.